# Joining every group of N lines into one with bash

Tags: bash

I would like to join every group of N lines in the output of another command using bash.

Are there any standard linux commands i can use to achieve this?

Example:

```
./command
    46.219464   0.000993    
    17.951781   0.002545    
    15.770583   0.002873    
    87.431820   0.000664    
    97.380751   0.001921    
    25.338819   0.007437
```

Desired output:

```
46.219464   0.000993     17.951781  0.002545
15.770583   0.002873     87.431820  0.000664    
97.380751   0.001921     25.338819  0.007437
```

Comment: Between `paste`, `pr`, `sed`,  `awk`, `xargs` and pure `bash`, [here is a comparission bench about *How to merges 16 lines*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348104/1765658)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your output has consistent number of fields, you can use `xargs -n N` to group on X elements per line:

```
$ ...command... | xargs -n4
46.219464 0.000993 17.951781 0.002545
15.770583 0.002873 87.431820 0.000664
97.380751 0.001921 25.338819 0.007437
```

From `man xargs`:

> **-n** max-args, **--max-args**=max-args
>
> Use  at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args
>   arguments will be used if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded,
>   unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.

Comment: `cmd... | paste -d " " - - - -` do same job **a lot faster**! Please have a look at *... do a little bench* paragraph on [Merge 16 lines into one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348104/1765658)! I compare 6 different way for this, `xargs` is the worst!!

Comment: this wins for speed of typing tho :)

Comment: @Goblinhack No, `pr -at2` is clearly shorter in chars **and** in executrion time!! Again: read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348104/1765658)

Answer (score 18):

Seems like you're trying to join every two lines with the delimiter `\t`(tab). If yes then you could try the below paste command,

```
command | paste -d'\t' - -
```

If you want space as  delimiter then use `-d<space>`,

```
command | paste -d' ' - -
```

Comment: and I can confirm that ```paste -d' ' - - - -``` works for 4 lines - legend!

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, `paste` seem to be the quickest solution! I've done a comparison bench, with six other solutions, on [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47348104/1765658) !